# MySQL error on special chars

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL database hosted in some provider. Everything was running ok for the last 3 years but somehow since yesterday all special characters are now show with invalid chars. For instance :

```
'sugestão' now shows as 'sugestÃ£o'
```

I did not make any changes in the database and the host company claims they can't do nothing to help. And most stranger yet, new inclusions are not being affected by this problem, only the data included prior to yesterday.

I know something happens in the host back-end, but they refuse to admit because they claim they don't have any logs to prove i did not change the DB charset or collation. But of course, i know i did not do this, this is an app running for 3 years and never had this problem.

So i'm on my own to fix the problem by updating all the columns with this kind of problem manually, in each table. Is there a way to do this faster inside MySql Workbench itself, instead of creating some app to it ?

For instance, i have a table called 'CRM'. Here is some example result set :

```
select * from crm;
cr_date     cr_history
2016-07-11  Quer sugestÃ£o 
2016-07-11  PaÃ­s de destino : CanadÃ¡
```

Here is how this result set looked before the problem and how i need to fix it to look back again :

```
select * from crm;
cr_date     cr_history
2016-07-11  Quer sugestão 
2016-07-11  PaÃ­s de destino : Canadá
```

Is there a way to do an update query to change all 'Ã£' strings inside a column to 'ã', keeping the rest of the column content intact ?

Something like this : replace all ocurencies o 'Ã£' in a field, to 'ã'. Something like PHP's str_replace but directly in Mysql.

Just to add more information, the DB it's accessed by a PHP application, but the problem happens accessing the DB directly from MySQL Workbench, so it's not a PHP related problem.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: My guess is that you don't set the encoding in PHP when you connect to MySQL and rely on defaults.

Comment: Like i said, the problem happens accessing the DB directly in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: The function is conveniently called [`replace`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace). Alternative: do a mysqldump, a full textreplace with your favourite editor/tool and reimport. (You have to take down your page for a bit then, and make sure your tool is case sensitive). If you have an old dump, you could check (and compare to the current dump) your first lines for entries like `SET NAMES`, charactersets or the mysql server version to see if there was a change. On the other hand, it can sometimes be a simple switch in your hosting config page.

Comment: I was just speculating about how invalid data arrived in the database in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very typical (and often seen) result when something stored UTF-8 data in an ANSI (or other non-UTF) column. PHP seems especially prone to this type of error (I've seen this several times before). So, when retrieving the data it is interpreted in the encoding of the column instead of its true encoding - hence the wrong display.

You can see this easily with something like this:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(_latin1'müller' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8);
+---------------------------------------------------+
| CAST(_latin1'müller' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8)  |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| mÃ¼ller                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CAST('müller' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8);
+--------------------------------------------+
| CAST('müller' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8)  |
+--------------------------------------------+
| müller                                     |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

What you can do is to set the right encoding (`charset` in (My)SQL) for that column. You could use an `ALTER TABLE` command, but this would mess up the existing values further (it would try to re-encode the already UTF-8 encoded values again in UTF-8). So a better approach is this:

- Add a new column with an UTF-8 charset + collation.
- UPDATE your table and set the values of the new column to the values of the old colum. Important here is [to cast](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html) the old column's charset to its true value (UTF-8). This will not convert the data but simply store the existing bytes in the new column, but this time with the correct encoding.
- Once done remove the old column and rename the new one to the old name.

With that additional column you make sure you don't lose data (a backup is still recommendable) and you can drop it and start over if something goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. What i don't understand is why this problem showed up from nowhere ; all was working fine. The host company claims they did not thing on their back end, either i changed anything on my app.